# Send data from a form to another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been asked to create a form and have the records from it go to another page (saved as a history).

I was asked to do a project in which a form is created on a web page, the data is stored in a database (using local storage), so far so good but I was asked to send those same records to another page (as a history of records that can be accessed quickly) the truth I have no idea how to send the records to a different page of the form, I hope you can.

```
<script>
    Swal.fire({
        position: 'top-end',
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Has guardado un registro',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
    })
</script>
 
    <div>
        <label>Auditor</label>
        <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="ddlAuditor"></asp:dropdownlist>
 
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Tablet</label>
        <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="ddlTablet"></asp:dropdownlist>
 
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Bateria</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBateria" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Cargador </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCargador" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
 
 
        <center>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEnCarga" OnClick="btnEnCarga_Click" Font-Size="Large" CssClass="btn btn-green" runat="server" Text="En carga" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnEnUso" OnClick="btnEnUso_Click" Font-Size="Large" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="En uso" />
            </center>
    </div>
 
<table id="listado" class='hide'>
    <thead>
        <th>Auditor</th>
        <th>Tablet</th>
        <th>Movimiento</th>
        <th>Eliminar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
 
 
<script>
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
 
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            const textoGuardado = localStorage.getItem(input.id);
            if (textoGuardado) {
                localStorage.removeItem(input.id);
            }
            const texto = input.value;
            localStorage.setItem(input.id, texto);
        });
 
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const textoGuardado = localStorage.getItem(input.id);
            if (textoGuardado) {
                input.value = textoGuardado;
            }
        });
    });
 
</script>
```

Comment: If the data is stored in `localStorage`, why can't the other page read that same data?

Comment: The whole concept of "saving to a database" is so that you don't *have* to "send" to another page - the other page just reads it from the database.

Comment: To send data from one page's form to another "page" you might use `<form action='other_page'..`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission though I think this will just confuse the issue.